# How to get MAX and MIN in GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select, group-by

In this query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
```

each row includes the first value of `col2` and `col3` for each unique value of `col1`.

How to select `MAX` and `MIN` for each value of `col1`.

Something like:

```
SELECT col1, minimum of col2, maximum of col2, minimum of col3, maximum of col3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Would you believe...

```
SELECT col1, MIN(col2), MAX(col2), MIN(col3), MAX(col3)
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY col1;
```

...?

---

> each row includes the first value of col2 and col3 for each unique value of col.

That assertion is not exactly true.  That may be what you're seeing, but do not assume this to be meaningful and do not write code based on this observation.  Your original query would not be valid at all were not for a MySQL extension that departs from standard SQL handling of `GROUP BY`.

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause.

...which is what you did in your initial query, col2 and col3 are not nonaggregated columns (columns without an aggregate function applied, and not in the group-by).  When you do this...

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html